# How can I modernify this piece of C++ code?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++98

I have an algorithm that is a piece of a mathematical equation parsing function I'm writing. It is inside the part where the current character (`c` or `*it`) has been determined to be a right-facing paranthesis `(` and is supposed to increment `it` until it finds the closing paranthesis.

```
       /* Iterate until the current character is the closing paranthesis or is off the end of the equation string */
        std::string::const_iterator opi = it;
        ++it;
        for (int nrfp = 1; nrfp > 0 && it != offend; c = *++it)
        {
            if (c == ')') --nrfp;
            else if (c == '(') ++nrfp;
        }
        if (it == offend) throw "Unbalanced parantheses";

        /* If we're here, the current character is the closing paranthesis, meaning the characters in the range (opi, it) are the inside of the paranthesis */

        /* Check that the paranthesis are not empty */
        if ((it - opi) == 1) throw "Empty paranthesis";
```

For reference, `opi` is supposed to mean "opening paranthesis iterator" and `nrfp` is supposed to mean "number of right-facing paranthesis" and `offend` is an iterator to the `end()` of the string I'm iteratring through.

How can I improve this in terms of readability, performance and modernity, without any compromise among the 3? Is there a standard library algorithm that I should be exploiting?

Comment: Why do you feel you need to "modernify" your code? Looks fine to me.

Comment: If the code has already been debugged and tested, I wouldn't risk modifying it.

Comment: `c = *++it` invokes undefined behavior if the increment results in the past-the-end iterator.

Comment: Seems to me there's a problem with your loop invariant.   You've told us that prior to this code c  = *it and c == '(' so far so good, then you advance the iterator to point to the next character (or end) and you set nrfp initially to 1, consistent with the fact you've seen one '(', fine, then you enter the loop and compare 'c' to either ')' or '(' ... which one will it compare equal to?  Is that what you intended? Probably not

Comment: Hint: if it != offend the 1st time you will enter the loop at least once, c will match '(' because you haven't updated it, and nrfp will now be 2, even though you've only seen one '('.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I think you need to do is: do NOT throw string-literals. Instead throw an object of exception class (eventually) derived from `std::exception`.

For example. replace this:

```
 if (it == offend) throw "Unbalanced parantheses";
```

with

```
 if (it == offend) throw std::runtime_error("Unbalanced parantheses");
```

Or an instance of `std::logic_error`, or some other (more specific) class. This modification will allow you to catch exceptions elegantly.  Read more about exceptions.